# Advantage of fit_generator() in keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, fitting, keras, generator

I was wondering if the `fit_generator()` in keras has any advantage in respect to memory usage over using the usual `fit()` method with the same `batch_size` as the generator yields. I've seen some examples similar to this:

```
def generator():
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# some data prep
...
while 1:
    for i in range(1875): # 1875 * 32 = 60000 -> # of training samples
        yield X_train[i*32:(i+1)*32], y_train[i*32:(i+1)*32]
```

If I pass this into the `fit_generator()` method or just pass all the data directly into the `fit()` method and define a `batch_size` of 32, would it make any difference regarding (GPU?)-memory whatsoever?